# Customized initializers and read only properties in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Before working with Objective-C and Core Data, I had occasions to create classes that needed to be initialized with certain parameters that, after initialization, could not be modified (though they could be read).

With Core Data, I believe I can create a customized init on my NSManagedObject derived class as long as it includes a way to insert the object into a context like such:

```
-(Cell*) initWithOwner:(CellList*)ownerCellList andLocation:(int)initLocation
{
    if (self = (Cell*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cell"
                        inManagedObjectContext:[ownerCellList managedObjectContext]])
    {
        self.location = [NSNumber numberWithInt:initLocation];
        self.owner = ownerCellList;
        [ownerCellList addCellListObject:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Normally, I'd have a location variable and the location property would be read-only (so once set at initialization, it could not be changed).  Is there a way to get this sort of pattern with Core Data?  Is there a better way I'm not thinking of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. As long as your initializer calls the `NSManagedObject`'s designated initializer, your approach is fine. You can also override the `-[NSManagedObject awakeFromInsert]` to perform some action after insertion (creation) or `-[NSManagedObject awakeFromFetch]` to perform an action (e.g. populating a cache) each time the object is faulted back into a managed object context.

Like the rest of Objective-C, there is no way to make a property truly readonly. Malicious code will likely be able to modify your property. However, in your custom class, you can declare a `@property(readonly)` for e.g. `location`. This will at least cause a warning if you try to modify the property and will signal your intent to client code.

Comment: Hmmm... just had another thought/question:  With the above init function, I would need to do an [[Cell alloc] initWith...] since it's not a class-level function.  Isn't that wrong to do with a Core Data object that's auto-released?  Would it be more appropriate to replace the initWith... function with a class-level function like createNewCellWithOwner:(CellList*)ownerCellList andLocation:(int)initLocation?  The call to insertNewObjectForEntityForName creates the new object and doesn't seem to belong in an init routine, right?

Comment: I didn't notice that initially. Yes, you're incurring a memory leak (from the initial +alloc) and you will get problems because you're not retaining the result of -insertNewObject...

I would use self = [self initWithEntity:entity inManagedObjectContext:[ownerCellIst managedObjectContext]] instead.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles here, reads the comments, and wonders at the final answer, it should be something like this. Continuing with the example above, it would be:

```
-(Cell*) initWithOwner:(CellList*)ownerCellList andLocation:(int)initLocation
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [ownerCellList managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel =
            [[context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];
    NSEntityDescription *entity =
            [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Cell"];
    self = [self initWithEntity:entity inManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (self)
    {
        self.location = [NSNumber numberWithInt:initLocation];
        self.owner = ownerCellList;
        [ownerCellList addCellListObject:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

[NSEntityDescription's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html)  `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` documentation says this is roughly how it converts from a given entityName (@"Cell") and a context (from `ownerCellList`) to an `NSManagedObject` instance.